# Best way to get field level exclusion/security on Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata

I have data which looks  like this :

```
[{
  "id":"1",
    "name": "Champ",
    "lastName": "Camp",
    "address": "1922 Breaking Change",
    "postalCode": "34802",
    "businessLine": "line1"
}, {
   "id":"2",
    "name": "Kamp",
    "lastName": "Mamp",
    "address": "1922 Breaking Change 1",
    "postalCode": "138283",
    "businessLine": "line2"
}, {
   "id":"3",
    "name": "Jamp",
    "lastName": "Tamp",
    "address": "1922 Breaking Change 2",
    "postalCode": "18941",
    "businessLine": "line1"
}, {
   "id":"4",
    "name": "Kamp",
    "lastName": "Mamp",
    "address": "1922 Breaking Change 1",
    "postalCode": "138283",
    "businessLine": "line2"
}, {
   "id":"5",
    "name": "Gamp",
    "lastName": "Damp",
    "address": "1922 Breaking Change 12",
    "postalCode": "121333",
    "businessLine": "line1"
}]
```

The problem is that I have to ensure security on the searchable fields related to businessLine. There are certain fields which are protected by businessLine level security. It means fields like name, postalCode, address are only **searchable** if you belong to a businessLine.

A scenario :
line1 has access to field "name" and line2 has access to field "postalCode".

So for user with access to businessLines,  line1 and line2, the field "name" will be searchable only in the documents with ids 1,2 and 5.
But the postal code will not be searchable on these documents.
The field postal code will only be searchable in documents with id 2 and 4.

I tried something and that works :

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "("name" :"amp" AND (businessline : line1 OR line3)) ("postalCode" :"amp" AND (businessline : line2 OR line3))"
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the desired results, but is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: A better way to do this is by using [document and field-level access control](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/field-and-document-access-control.html) available in XPack, though this is a commercial product.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/setting-up-field-and-document-level-security.html